# Delivery mechanism for JavaScript bundle consumed by multiple clients

Tags: javascript, micro-frontend

**Scenario**:

A shared component implemented as a micro-front-end and hosted on S3...

- JS bundle containing the whole app (webpacked) hosted on S3
- JS bundle contains hash with the latest commit, e.g. component.{hash}.js

**Question**:

When we ship a new bundle, what's the best strategy for ensuring the new bundle is consumed by all clients after release, taking into account browser/CDN caching? Important note: we would like client's to get updates immediately (internal).

**Examples**

1. On release, generate a component.html file that pulls in the bundle (script tag) based on the latest hash. Ship the new component.html to S3. Clients use `<link rel-'import' href='somedomain.com/component.html'>` always giving them the latest shipped version.

Issue: The bundle can still take advantage of CD/browser caching, but the HTML file cannot be cached since we need it to be hot for any release. Also seems odd that we have to make two downloads to just get to a single bundle.

2. Ship as an NPM module that can be consumed at build time by a client.

Issue: If we have 10 clients, all 10 need to build and ship to release with the new component. Assuming package.lock won't cause issues for wildcards (don't know it well enough).

Note: Internal component; may undergo frequent changes, e.g. AB testing, etc.

Comment: What are "clients" in this context?  Developers that are using your module?  Or, users' browsers?

Answer (score 0):

It's generally important that page/app consuming your component be tested and updated with whatever new version of your component is released.  Therefore, your idea of using NPM is a good one.  It's generally desirable to have this lag time, so that developers of the pages/apps can verify functionality and also handle any API changes that may have occurred (intentional or otherwise).

For NPM, [Semantic Versioning (SemVer)](https://semver.org/) is a defacto standard.  The idea is that you number your versions in such a way that bugfixes (no API changes) can be immediately updated in apps.  *Some* developers are okay with installing the latest patch-version of your module.  *Many* prefer to lock to a specific version, and will only release after testing like any other update.

NPM aside, what I've done in the past is use hashed or versioned URLs for the library.  I've also kept a `latest` URL, which redirects to the latest version.  For those integrating my library that don't care what version they're on, they'll always get the latest version this way.  Additionally, browsers can cache the redirect target and share that cache with other pages that might specify an exact version.

> Important note: we would like client's to get updates immediately (internal).

This isn't really all that possible in all cases.  In *most* cases, using proper response headers for caching will solve it.  There are edge cases though.  For example, what will you do if the user loads a page and then goes offline before your JavaScript loads?

It's always tricky when deploying new pages.  Some of your clients will be on old versions, some on new.  Maintain backwards compatibility as best as you can, and set your caching headers as appropriate for your circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for this Brad. What we are deploying here is a front end however, not really a library. Think micro-front end architecture. So, multiple teams could own different parts of a single page. For example, a team owns and deploys a header/footer, etc. Client in this sense would be the team owning the actual page in which all of this comes together. So, if my team own the header for example, I may want to ship an update and have that available for any page consuming it. That could be an AB test, bug fix or some other change that the business need ASAP. So NPM doesn’t work here.

Comment: Header is a bad example, but used for simplicity.

Comment: @Adrian Your question says "JS bundle".  Is that not what it is?  Private NPM would work fine for that, and so would my other suggestion.

Comment: Yes. A JS bundle which is a front end. Implementation could be anything, e.g. React+Custom Web Component. The non NPM solution you mentioned is similar to having a HTML file. As you point out you will have edge cases around caching.